# Xamarin.iOS getting issues with OneSignal when deploying

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, onesignal

I am having an issue integrating OneSignal with my Xamarin.IOS app. I create and app from scratch and then follow the sdk guide on their website, however, after adding the SDK once I try and deploy to my apple device I get the below error.

This does not happen when deploying to a simulator and I have tried two different Apple Devices.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsmE7.png)

**Update**

The issue seemed to be with my version of the mono framework. I was using Visual studio for mac preview which uses mono version 4.8, however, this is still in the alpha branch.

I then used Xamarin Studio and downgrade mono to 4.6 (Stable Build) and everything worked fine.

Comment: Please don't post errors as screenshots, paste the text of the errors instead. This allows for people searching on the error to find this question and also makes it easier to search on the error. Also, Can you supply a MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You have used Native Libray bridge? Please make sure the static library used is FAT library and not only for simulator.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replies, this was my first post on StackOverflow so in the future I will make my posts more useful for people searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using OSNotificationPayload class from iOS native library (.a file). The error means that library is not loaded for the current architecture. 
As its working on Simulator, .a is for simulator only.

You can verify this using Lipo command:

```
 lipo -info YourLibrary.a
```

Get .a file for device and simulator both and generate fat library from it and use it. It will resolve your problem.

here is command to create universal FAT library - copied from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/):

```
lipo -create -output libMyLibrary.a libMyLibrary-i386.a libMyLibrary-arm64.a libMyLibrary-armv7.a
```

Comment: Thanks for the above, it proved useful and actually solved other problems that I have been encountering, however this specific issue resolved itself when I downgraded my mono version to stable release of 4.6